# AVC or A.V.C or A.V.C

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, periods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to drop the periods in abbreviations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/is-it-ok-to-drop-the-periods-in-abbreviations)

Okay, so in School I was always tought that when we want to abbreviate, we must use a full stop "." inbetween each letter, and if it's at the end of a sentence, a full stop at the end also (duh).

But, everywhere I go now, I am faced with having to put up with bad grammar, incorrectly-spelled words, and just total rubish. And I believe marketing is to blame! Think about it... When was the last time you saw a major company with a nice looking logo like AVC use dots inbetween each letter?

It's become so widely accepted that everybody does it now - all the time. Now I'm getting confused because all I've seen for a long time is just total rubbish, and now I don't remember which way is correct or not.

Say for example the following letters stand for "Another" "Silly" "Word", which version of abbreviation is correct?

> A.S.W
>   A.S.W.
>   ASW

Or are they all correct?

Comment: I have never seen the final period (full stop) eliminated from an abbreviation... is that common?

Comment: I think you should only use a final period in an abbreviation when it's the end of a sentence or when there are no words before or after the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Michael Swan's Practical English Usage:

> We ususally write abbreviations
>   without full stops in modern British
>   English. Full stops are normal in
>   American English.

Collins Cobuild English Dictionary:

> PS: also P.S.

I guess A.S.W. and ASW are correct uses then.

Comment: Thanks, @masarah. It was driving me insane. I think I'll keep using dots, I think it looks weird without them.