# When to use or omit periods in acronyms, abbreviations, and initials

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, abbreviations, periods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to drop the periods in abbreviations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/is-it-ok-to-drop-the-periods-in-abbreviations)

I don't understand when or where to use or discard a period when writing short forms.

For example, my college is the Malaviya National Institute of Technology. Should I abbreviate it as *M.N.I.T.* or is *MNIT* better?

A second example, for Windows *Portable Executable*, is it "P.E.", "PE", or "PE."?

Lastly, if I write out my project's name UNMP, should I capitalize all words or just the first one? "Unified Network Management Platform" vs. "Unified network management platform".

I often have this question when writing papers/resumes.

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks!..I couldn't find before posing my question. And my question is bit different too.

Comment: Tip: In the question, I would write "Windows", "capitalised", "paper" and "résumé" (or "CV").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Punctuation in abbreviations](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-abbreviations):

> 1. In both British and American English, if you are using initial (i.e. first) letters to represent words, you don’t normally need to
>      put a full stop after them:
>
>    BBC
>
>    NATO
> 2. In American English, however, it is common to use a full stop as an alternative style for certain abbreviations, in particular:
>
>    USA or U.S.A.

So in your case, *MNIT* and *Windows PE* are fine. Also, I would capitalize the first words in those abbreviations: *United Management ...*