# What is the correct format for using commas after periods?

Tags: punctuation, commas, abbreviations, periods

Basically, I wish to write something along the lines of

> Bob, C.J., Greg and Charles all went to the store.

I'm not sure about the use of the comma after the *C.J.* Is this correct punctuation? Are there better, less awkward, alternatives?

Comment: And also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/is-it-ok-to-drop-the-periods-in-abbreviations will help, I think.

Answer (score 4):

I agree a comma immediately following a period or full stop does look weird, but it would look worse without!

> "Bob, **C.J,** Greg and Charles all went to the store."

So your way of punctuating was in the end, correct.

> Bob, **C.J.,** Greg and Charles all went to the store.

The rule is that a comma mustn't go after an initial, ever.

I did a bit of research to double check and I didn't find anything that contradicted my gut feeling.

http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/ponctuation-punctuation/etc-eng.html

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Should_there_be_a_comma_after_the_abbreviation_Inc

However, you could change *the order* of names thereby avoiding the inaesthetic coupling of the period and comma.

> "Bob, Greg, Charles and **C.J.** all went to the store."

EDIT: I thought it best to rephrase and change the original modal verb, "shouldn't" to "mustn't"  to avoid any possible misinterpretation. I hope, I've made myself clearer!

Answer (score 2):

The periods in C.J. don't punctuate.  They act more like *letters*, and can thus be considered *spelling* rather than punctuation.  Spelling doesn't affect how you use commas, so feel free to use a comma after C.J. whenever it makes sense to do so.

The only exception I can think of is when you end a sentence with a word that ends with a period.  In that case, the period has to do double duty: it's both spelling *and* punctuation.  Adding a second period would go against convention.