# Where does the term ‘Messers’ come from in reference to a group of people?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I’ve heard this term used in films and by British politicians

Comment: Answered at [Is it proper to omit periods after honorifics: Mr / Mrs / Dr](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/is-it-proper-to-omit-periods-after-honorifics-mr-mrs-dr/101459#101459) where Sven Yargs quotes CMOS: 'Chicago (fifteenth edition, 2003):

15.16 Social titles. Always abbreviated, whether preceding the full name or the surname only, are such social titles as the following:

Ms. Mrs. Messrs. Mr. Dr.' and 'The plural of Mr. is Messrs; the plural of Mrs. is Mmes.'. There's an obvious French connection.

Comment: You might wonder why the British use the French term "Messrs/Messieurs" rather than "Misters". Is that what you're asking? Or were you totally unaware of the term "Messrs"?

Comment: @StuartF: Indeed, that's probably what Jord was asking, and why they had to close it is beyond me.